# SQL Statement - SELECT * with MAX()

Tags: php, sql, select, max

I have 4 columns called ID, EQUIPID, VERSION, DESCRIPTION. Users can add additional columns so the SQL statement needs to be dynamic. The column ID is unique and will never duplicate; EQUIPID describes an equipment which means multiple EQUIPIDs can be the same; and VERSION describes the difference between the same EQUIPID entries.

How can i query to SELECT * and get only one of each EQUIPID with largest VERSION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT tn.*
    FROM table_name tn
   WHERE tn.version =
          (SELECT MAX(sq.version)
             FROM table_name sq
            WHERE sq.equipid = tn.equipid);
```

Basically, select rows where the version is equal to the max version for that equipid.

Comment: If you love it, put a ring on it (accept... helps others discern good answers from bad - like the highest-rated answer so far).

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from yourtable
where ID in (
   select max(ID)
   from
   yourtable
   where EQUIPID = xxx
);
```

The inner query gets the highest ID of the specified equipment, then the outer query pulls up the rest of the data on that equipment record.

Comment: hmm I don't think that's right. the OP wanted the largest VERSION not the largest ID for each equipid

Comment: @Conrad: but since the IDs are automatically assigned and never repeat, the highest version implies the highest ID as well.

Comment: @Marc B maybe maybe not, also what is XXX supposed to be?

Comment: @Marc: That seems like a silly assumption, especially when you can just compare version (assuming it can be compared correctly). I mean, by that logic, Star Wars Episode IV "takes place" before Star Wars Episode I since it came out first.

Comment: OP wants to get max VERSION and "one of each EQUIPID." This answer *maybe* does the former and definitely doesn't do the latter.

Comment: @webbiedave: in that case, just replace the inner where with a `group by (equipid)`

Comment: so much for the "one of each EQUIPID" requirement

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY EquipID
HAVING max(Version)
```

another way to create temporary table and then join from both table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE tmp
    -> SELECT name, MAX(Version) AS max_ver
    -> FROM tableName GROUP BY EquipID;
mysql> SELECT t.*
    -> FROM tableName t, tmp
    -> WHERE t.id = tmp.id
```

OR using self JOIN

```
select *
from tableName tn
where (
   select count(*) from table t
   where t.equipId = tn.equipId and t.version > tn.version
) <= 2;
```

Comment: When grouping, you're not guaranteed to get the same values in the individual fields - with MySQL, you tend to get the first value found, which would be from a lower id.

Comment: reference : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it

```
SELECT yt.* 
FROM   yourtable yt 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT equipid, 
                          Max(version) AS version 
                   FROM   yourtable) AS maxversion 
         ON yt.equipid = maxversion.equipid 
            AND yt.version = maxversion.version;
```

But depending on your database you can do it in other ways. e.g using ROW_NUMBER()